# Adding anmob ads to my viewpager, get an error not enough space for ads

Tags: tabs, admob, swipe

How can I make admob advertisements show on my app, as I get a response saying that there is not enough space to show ads.

I would like the admob ads to be at the bottom of the screen, and be in all the swipe through tabs.

What am I doing wrong?

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
    ActionBar.TabListener {

private ViewPager viewPager;
private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
private ActionBar actionBar;
// Tab titles
private String[] tabs = { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5" };

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Initilization
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

    actionBar = getActionBar();
    mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());


    viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);        

    // Adding Tabs
    for (String tab_name : tabs) {
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                .setTabListener(this));
    }



            /**
     * on swiping the viewpager make respective tab selected
     * */
    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            // on changing the page
            // make respected tab selected
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // on tab selected
    // show respected fragment view
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view. This fragment
 * would include your content.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ad, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}

/**
 * This class makes the ad request and loads the ad.
 */
public static class AdFragment extends Fragment {

    private AdView mAdView;

    public AdFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onActivityCreated(bundle);

        // Gets the ad view defined in layout/ad_fragment.xml with ad unit ID set in
        // values/strings.xml.
        mAdView = (AdView) getView().findViewById(R.id.adView);

        // Create an ad request. Check logcat output for the hashed device ID to
        // get test ads on a physical device. e.g.
        // "Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("ABCDEF012345") to get test ads on this device."
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);




        // Start loading the ad in the background.
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ad, container, false);
    }

    /** Called when leaving the activity */
    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        if (mAdView != null) {
            mAdView.pause();
        }
        super.onPause();
    }

    /** Called when returning to the activity */
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (mAdView != null) {
            mAdView.resume();
        }
    }

    /** Called before the activity is destroyed */
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        if (mAdView != null) {
            mAdView.destroy();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Show your layout xml. One of the containers of the AdView has specified a margin that has reduced the room available to the AdView until it is too small.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the Layout xml

tab fragment layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#fa6a6a">

<TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Tab 1"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/pager"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">


<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/adFragment"
    android:name="com.softyaps.app.MainActivity$AdFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
</RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

adfragment layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

</RelativeLayout>
```